# CP-SAT: how to use AddAllDifferent in optimization?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I would like a set of variables to have different values, but not enforce it strictly. I.e., it is straightforward to do:

```
model.AddAllDifferent([var1, var2, var3])
```

But how can I use it only in optimization and not enforce it strictly? The way that usually works is to enforce constraint based on a boolean variable, but then I'd need a negation of the constraint, too:

```
model.AddAllDifferent([var1, var2, var3]).OnlyEnforceIf(satisfiable)
model.AddSomeSame([var1, var2, var3]).OnlyEnforceIf(satisfiable.Not())
model.Maximize(satisfiable)
```

(I made `AddSomeSame` up, obviously.)

I am not aware of what I could use to negate `AddAllDifferent`. Constructing a constraint for "at least two of the variables have the same value" manually seems a bit tedious.

Is there a reasonable approach to this problem? Ideally one that can be used also to use `AddAllowedAssignments` in optimization (seems to me as analogous problem)?

Comment: I think you may have to do everything manually, `AddAllDifferent` doesn't accept enforcement literals. `AddAllowedAssignments` neither

Comment: That's what I am afraid. Thinking about it more, it would be nice and elegant if I can add the enforcement boolean variable and use it in optimization.

Comment: They might help you formulate it over at https://or.stackexchange.com/